# Can't open or create projects: The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.Projects.MSBuild.MSBuildEvaluationContext' threw an exception

Tags: visual-studio-mac

This morning, I found I was unable to create or open any projects on Visual Studio Community for macOS v8.1.1 (build 27) without getting the error...

> The project could not be created
>
> The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.Projects.MSBuild.MSBuildEvaluationContext' threw an exception.

This install of VS has been working for quite some time on this Mac. VS had found and installed some updates recently. This is not a box where I work routinely; it may have last worked successfully a week or so ago.

Here is a screencapture when trying to create a Console app project, for instance. The error occurs when I hit the "Create" button.

[image: Picture of The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.Projects.MSBuild.MSBuildEvaluationContext' threw an exception from the New Project screen]

I've found a very similar error on a now defunct Bugzilla for the old [Xamarin Studio here](https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/57/57085/bug.html), which links me to [this resolved GitHub issue](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/pull/2546) on MonoDevelop, which is now Visual Studio, from 2017, which is marked Closed and Merged.

I've also found a very similar error report raised as another [GitHub issue for MonoDevelop here](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/6684). No clear resolution there; just a reply that, "*Seems like MSBuild is not installed?*"

They both suggest MSBuild isn't in the right place, but I'm not sure how I'd fix that.

I have tried uninstalling Visual Studio (by trashing) and removing .NET using `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet`. This removed .NET, but on reinstall of VS and .NET, the error returns.

Is there a better way to perform a clean install? Is there another way to resolve this issue?

---

**Round 2**

Since the issue was MonoDevelop specific, I did a `find` to find any file with `mono` in it. I found some stuff like this...

`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono`

... in the Frameworks folder, and that looked promising. I've messed with MonoDevelop in the past (remember [icsharpcode](http://icsharpcode.net)?), know that it used to be its own, independent, OSS C# IDE, and blasted that `Mono.framework` folder away.

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/`

I also deleted Visual Studio and removed `/usr/local/share/dotnet` again, then reinstalled .NET and VS with the VS installer.

When I tried to open Visual Studio, I got a different message.

[image: Could not launch Visual Studio This application requires a newer version of the Mono framework]

Now we're getting somewhere. I clicked the "Download Mono Framework" button in that dialog and initially tried installing the "Visual Studio" release from the page the button opened, tried reopening VS, and *got the same error as before*. Strangely, the VS release is **5.18.1.3**, and the error message, above, says I need **5.18.1.24+**. :thinking-face:

I tried downloading the latest "Stable" release of the mono framework instead, which is version **5.20.1.19**.

[image: What version of Mono is needed for Visual Studio macOS]

Visual Studio opens and creates new projects without error, but...

**EDIT:** That was short lived. I now get a `/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.700/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(5,5): Error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.DependencyContextBuilder:_filteredPackages' (12) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000025 from typeref ...`

error when I try to build the stock console app.

---

**NOTE:** There is [an official process for deleting Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/macos/#uninstalling-mono-on-macos) I missed, and is better than the quick & dirty `rm -rf` I tried, above.

Comment: No. You must use a compatible Mono release (like 5.18.1.28). 5.20 is for vNext, so it can break everything.

Comment: VS Mac 8.1 and Mono 5.18.1.28 should work OK with .NET Core 2.1.700. Not seen that particular error before - looks like some sort of mismatch with Mono's MSBuild and .NET Core sdk. I think Mono 5.20 is missing some updated NuGet files used for buliding. I would install [Mono 5.18.1.28](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/d709da85-c472-437d-9e3d-34d0aece1f1d/1795624d8fe42827f89625fd8553d79b/monoframework-mdk-5.18.1.28.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg).

Comment: @MattWard That one worked for me. How did you find it?

Comment: That Mono link should be the one offered if you run the check for updates in VS Mac  with the Stable channel selected.

Comment: Temporarily got around this by using the Preview release. Will try to downgrade this weekend and will check back in.